# How to split innherHTML string using Javascript into specific parts after a certain character like a '+' sign

Tags: javascript, html

I need to break a string apart after certain characters.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Monster + "<p id='vault" + loop + "'> || HP: " + HP + "</p>" + " || Defense: " + Def + " || Attack: " + ATK + " || Can it Dodge/Block: " + DB + " || Can it retaliate: " + RET + " || Initative: " + INT + " || Exp: " + MEXP + "  <input type='submit' class='new' onclick='Combat(" + loop + ")' value='FIGHT!'></input>" + "<br><br>" + A;




 function Chest(id){
    window.open('LootGen.html', '_blank');
 }
 function Combat(id){
    document.getElementById("C").value = document.getElementById("vault" + id).innerHTML;
 }
```

When this runs the value that results is:

> |+HP:+20

However I only want '20' part,now keep in mind that this variable does change and so I need to use substrings to somehow pull that second number after the `+`. I've seen this done with:

> var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

This doesn't work here for some reason as first of all the var is an `innher html`.
Could someone please point me in the write direction as I'm not very good at reading docs.

Comment: You would probably do better if you read javascript information rather than javadocs (java is server, javascript is client and very much different). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript is an outstanding resource for this.

Comment: google -> 'regexp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a combination of substring and lastIndexOf will allow you to get the substring from the last spot of the occurrence of the "+".

Note the + 1  moves the index to exclude the "+" character. To include it you would need to remove the + 1

```
function Combat(id){
    var vaultInner = document.getElementById("vault" + id).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("C").value = vaultInner.substring(vaultInner.lastIndexOf("+") + 1);
}
```

Comment: I posted a second answer below that uses the array method that you had posted var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = "|+HP:+20";
// Break string into an array of strings and grab last element
var results = text.split('+').pop();
```

References:

- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Answer (score 0):

the code example using the split would give you an array of stuff separated by the plus

```
function Combat(id){
    //splits into an array
    var vaultInner = document.getElementById("vault" + id).innerHTML.split("+");
    //returns last element
    document.getElementById("C").value = vaultInner[vaultInner.length -1];
}
```

Comment: This answer maybe more beneficial if you were going to use the other strings within this function or needed other logic